# Fail2Ban not banning, Regex shows many fails in logs

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

I have the following jail defined in my /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf. For privacy/security I've replaced references to IPs with local 10.0.0.x addresses.

```
[ssh-iptables]

enabled  = true
filter   = sshd
banaction = iptables[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]
logpath  = /var/log/secure
backend =   auto
findtime = 18000
bantime = 65535
maxretry = 5
```

Using the filter available [here](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/35591db3e854af89038e230b47a75b8978ed84fd/config/filter.d/sshd.conf) for sshd. I did attempt to add this line:

`^.*authentication failure;.*rhost=<HOST>` to the file as suggested by [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/632774/fail2ban-on-centos-6-5-never-bans)

When I run `fail2ban-regex /var/log/secure /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf` I get many hits indicated as failures. Below is a sample based on 150 lines of /var/log/secure from earlier today.

```
$ cat /tmp/output.txt

Running tests
=============

Use regex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf
Use log file   : /tmp/failed3.log


Results
=======

Failregex: 56 total
|- #) [# of hits] regular expression
|  3) [42] ^\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s(?:\[ID \d+ \S+\])?\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Failed \S+ for (?P<cond_inv>invalid user )?(?P<user>(?P<cond_user>\S+)|(?(cond_inv)(?:(?! from ).)*?|[^:]+)) from <HOST>(?: port \d+)?(?: on \S+(?: port \d+)?)?(?: ssh\d*)?(?(cond_user): |(?:(?:(?! from ).)*)$)
|  13) [14] ^\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s(?:\[ID \d+ \S+\])?\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?pam_unix\(sshd:auth\):\s+authentication failure;\s*logname=\S*\s*uid=\d*\s*euid=\d*\s*tty=\S*\s*ruser=\S*\s*rhost=<HOST>\s.*(?: \[preauth\])?\s*$
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Summary
=======

Addresses found:
[3]
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:46:29 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:46:32 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:46:34 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:46:43 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:46:46 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:46:48 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:46:59 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:02 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:03 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:15 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:17 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:20 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:30 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:32 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:34 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:45 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:48 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:51 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:03 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:06 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:08 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:18 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:21 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:23 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:38 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:40 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:43 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:50 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:53 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:55 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:07 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:10 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:13 2020)
    10.0.0.2 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:20 2020)
    10.0.0.2 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:23 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:24 2020)
    10.0.0.2 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:25 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:27 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:29 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:37 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:40 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:43 2020)
[13]
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:46:27 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:46:41 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:46:57 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:13 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:28 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:47:44 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:01 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:16 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:35 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:48:48 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:05 2020)
    10.0.0.2 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:18 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:22 2020)
    10.0.0.1 (Mon Feb 24 11:49:35 2020)

Date template hits:
2606 hit(s): MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second

Success, the total number of match is 56

However, look at the above section 'Running tests' which could contain important
information.
```

Increasing log level to 4 produces this output.

```
2020-02-24 12:33:24,612 fail2ban.server : INFO   Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.8.10
2020-02-24 12:33:24,612 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['add', 'ssh-iptables', 'auto']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,613 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'ssh-iptables'
2020-02-24 12:33:24,633 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-iptables' uses pyinotify
2020-02-24 12:33:24,647 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Setting usedns = warn for FilterPyinotify(Jail('ssh-iptables'))
2020-02-24 12:33:24,652 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Created FilterPyinotify(Jail('ssh-iptables'))
2020-02-24 12:33:24,653 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Created FilterPyinotify
2020-02-24 12:33:24,653 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
2020-02-24 12:33:24,654 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'usedns', 'warn']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,654 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Setting usedns = warn for FilterPyinotify(Jail('ssh-iptables'))
2020-02-24 12:33:24,654 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addlogpath', '/var/log/secure']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,663 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/secure
2020-02-24 12:33:24,663 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Added monitor for the parent directory /var/log
2020-02-24 12:33:24,663 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Added file watcher for /var/log/secure
2020-02-24 12:33:24,663 fail2ban.filter.datedetector: DEBUG  Sorting the template list
2020-02-24 12:33:24,664 fail2ban.filter.datedetector: DEBUG  Winning template: MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second with 0 hits
2020-02-24 12:33:24,664 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'maxretry', '5']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,664 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 5
2020-02-24 12:33:24,665 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addignoreip', '127.0.0.1/8,']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,665 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Add 127.0.0.1/8, to ignore list
2020-02-24 12:33:24,665 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addignoreip', 10.0.0.0/8’]
2020-02-24 12:33:24,666 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Add 10.0.0.0/8 to ignore list
2020-02-24 12:33:24,666 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'findtime', '18000']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,666 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 18000
2020-02-24 12:33:24,667 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'bantime', '65535']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,667 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 65535
2020-02-24 12:33:24,667 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error|failed) for .* from <HOST>( via \\S+)?\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,670 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User not known to the underlying authentication module for .* from <HOST>\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,681 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Failed \\S+ for (?P<cond_inv>invalid user )?(?P<user>(?P<cond_user>\\S+)|(?(cond_inv)(?:(?! from ).)*?|[^:]+)) from <HOST>(?: port \\d+)?(?: on \\S+(?: port \\d+)?)?(?: ssh\\d*)?(?(cond_user): |(?:(?:(?! from ).)*)$)']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,685 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?ROOT LOGIN REFUSED.* FROM <HOST>\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,696 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user .*? from <HOST>(?: port \\d+)?(?: on \\S+(?: port \\d+)?)?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,699 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,703 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because listed in DenyUsers\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,714 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not in any group\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,718 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?refused connect from \\S+ \\(<HOST>\\)\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,729 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Received disconnect from <HOST>(?: port \\d+)?(?: on \\S+(?: port \\d+)?)?:\\s*3: .*: Auth fail(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,733 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because a group is listed in DenyGroups\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,746 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', "^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$"]
2020-02-24 12:33:24,750 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?pam_unix\\(sshd:auth\\):\\s+authentication failure;\\s*logname=\\S*\\s*uid=\\d*\\s*euid=\\d*\\s*tty=\\S*\\s*ruser=\\S*\\s*rhost=<HOST>\\s.*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,766 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?(error: )?maximum authentication attempts exceeded for .* from <HOST>(?: port \\d+)?(?: on \\S+(?: port \\d+)?)?(?: ssh\\d*)? \\[preauth\\]$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,771 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^(?P<__prefix>\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ not allowed because account is locked(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$<SKIPLINES>^(?P=__prefix)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Received disconnect from <HOST>: 11: .+(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,788 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^(?P<__prefix>\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for .+?(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$<SKIPLINES>^(?P=__prefix)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Connection closed by <HOST>(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,794 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^(?P<__prefix>\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Connection from <HOST>(?: port \\d+)?(?: on \\S+(?: port \\d+)?)?(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$<SKIPLINES>^(?P=__prefix)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for .+(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,808 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['start', 'ssh-iptables']
2020-02-24 12:33:24,808 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-iptables' started
2020-02-24 12:33:24,812 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  pyinotifier started for ssh-iptables.
2020-02-24 12:33:26,493 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Default Callback for Event: <Event dir=False mask=0x2 maskname=IN_MODIFY name='' path=/var/log/secure pathname=/var/log/secure wd=2 >
2020-02-24 12:33:26,493 fail2ban.filter.datedetector: DEBUG  Matched time template MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
2020-02-24 12:33:26,494 fail2ban.filter.datedetector: DEBUG  Matched time template MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
2020-02-24 12:33:26,498 fail2ban.filter.datedetector: DEBUG  Got time using template MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
2020-02-24 12:33:26,498 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Processing line with time:1582559963.0 and ip:PROBLEM-IP
2020-02-24 12:33:40,959 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['status']
2020-02-24 12:33:45,745 fail2ban.comm   : DEBUG  Command: ['status', 'ssh-iptables']
```

The line `2020-02-24 12:33:26,498 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Processing line with time:1582559963.0 and ip:PROBLEM-IP` corresponds with the first entry in my secure log currently (the file has been truncated since it hadn't been rotated in awhile). However there are several hundred similar lines in the secure logs:

```
$ sudo grep "Failed password" /var/log/secure | grep 10.0.0.1 | wc -l
1182
```

Pyinotify has been installed (`sudo yum install pyinotify -y`) and NTP is configured and active, my logs dates/times are in sync with the time given by `date`.

```
$ ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (209.51.161.238) at stratum 2
   time correct to within 26 ms
   polling server every 512 s
$ date
Mon Feb 24 12:56:34 EST 2020
$ tail /var/log/secure -n1
Feb 24 12:56:37 localhost sshd[24764]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.0.0.1  user=root
```

Other info:

```
Fail2Ban v0.8.10

Copyright (c) 2004-2008 Cyril Jaquier, 2008- Fail2Ban Contributors
Copyright of modifications held by their respective authors.
Licensed under the GNU General Public License v2 (GPL).

Written by Cyril Jaquier <cyril.jaquier@fail2ban.org>.
Many contributions by Yaroslav O. Halchenko <debian@onerussian.com>.
```

fail2ban-client -d output

```
$ sudo fail2ban-client -d
WARNING 'action' not defined in 'ssh-messages'. Using default one: ''
['set', 'loglevel', 4]
['set', 'logtarget', '/var/log/fail2ban.log']
['add', 'ssh-iptables', 'auto']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'usedns', 'warn']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addlogpath', '/var/log/secure']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'maxretry', 5]
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addignoreip', '127.0.0.1/8,']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addignoreip', '10.0.0.0/8']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'findtime', 18000]
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'bantime', 65535]
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error|failed) for .* from <HOST>( via \\S+)?\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User not known to the underlying authentication module for .* from <HOST>\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Failed \\S+ for (?P<cond_inv>invalid user )?(?P<user>(?P<cond_user>\\S+)|(?(cond_inv)(?:(?! from ).)*?|[^:]+)) from <HOST>(?: port \\d+)?(?: on \\S+(?: port \\d+)?)?(?: ssh\\d*)?(?(cond_user): |(?:(?:(?! from ).)*)$)']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?ROOT LOGIN REFUSED.* FROM <HOST>\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user .*? from <HOST>(?: port \\d+)?(?: on \\S+(?: port \\d+)?)?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because listed in DenyUsers\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not in any group\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?refused connect from \\S+ \\(<HOST>\\)\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Received disconnect from <HOST>(?: port \\d+)?(?: on \\S+(?: port \\d+)?)?:\\s*3: .*: Auth fail(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because a group is listed in DenyGroups\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', "^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$"]
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?pam_unix\\(sshd:auth\\):\\s+authentication failure;\\s*logname=\\S*\\s*uid=\\d*\\s*euid=\\d*\\s*tty=\\S*\\s*ruser=\\S*\\s*rhost=<HOST>\\s.*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?(error: )?maximum authentication attempts exceeded for .* from <HOST>(?: port \\d+)?(?: on \\S+(?: port \\d+)?)?(?: ssh\\d*)? \\[preauth\\]$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^(?P<__prefix>\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?User .+ not allowed because account is locked(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$<SKIPLINES>^(?P=__prefix)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Received disconnect from <HOST>: 11: .+(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^(?P<__prefix>\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for .+?(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$<SKIPLINES>^(?P=__prefix)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Connection closed by <HOST>(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addfailregex', '^(?P<__prefix>\\s*(<[^.]+ [^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Connection from <HOST>(?: port \\d+)?(?: on \\S+(?: port \\d+)?)?(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$<SKIPLINES>^(?P=__prefix)(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for .+(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'addaction', 'iptables']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'actionban', 'iptables', 'iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype>']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'actionstop', 'iptables', 'iptables -D <chain> -p <protocol> --dport <port> -j fail2ban-<name>\niptables -F fail2ban-<name>\niptables -X fail2ban-<name>']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'actionstart', 'iptables', 'iptables -N fail2ban-<name>\niptables -A fail2ban-<name> -j RETURN\niptables -I <chain> -p <protocol> --dport <port> -j fail2ban-<name>']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'actionunban', 'iptables', 'iptables -D fail2ban-<name> -s <ip> -j <blocktype>']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'actioncheck', 'iptables', "iptables -n -L <chain> | grep -q 'fail2ban-<name>[ \\t]'"]
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'setcinfo', 'iptables', 'blocktype', 'REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'setcinfo', 'iptables', 'protocol', 'tcp']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'setcinfo', 'iptables', 'name', 'SSH']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'setcinfo', 'iptables', 'chain', 'INPUT']
['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'setcinfo', 'iptables', 'port', 'ssh']
['start', 'ssh-iptables']
```

iptables -L

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Of note if I run `fail2ban-client set ssh-iptables banip IPADDR` the given will be added to iptables, and is displayed using the rDNS name of the given IP (at least for server I am testing with).

```
$ sudo fail2ban-client set ssh-iptables banip 10.0.0.10
10.0.0.10
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  REVERSE-DNS-NAME-FOR-10.0.0.10  anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I'm fairly new to fail2ban and probably missing something obvious but I'm struggling to determine what at this point. From what I can parse given the output above it seems like it should be working but I am getting 0 bans despite watching dozens of failures scroll by from the same IP in the secure log.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "correct" solution but I was able to get the `ssh-iptables` jail working by reinstalling, recreating jail.local and changing the contents of the jail.local to:

```
[DEFAULT]

bantime  = 600
ignorecommand =
findtime  = 600
maxretry = 3
usedns = warn
banaction = iptables-multiport
banaction_allports = iptables-allports

[ssh-iptables]

enabled  = true
filter   = sshd
action   = iptables-allports[name=SSH, protocol=tcp]
backend =   polling
logpath  = /var/log/secure
pathname = /var/log/secure
bantime = 86400
findtime = 1200
mode    =   normal
maxretry = 5

## disabled jails removed to save space ##
```

For some reason changing the banaction from `iptables` to `iptables-allports` worked for me, [as suggested by IgorG on nearly 5 year old Plesk support post](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/plesk-12-5-fail2ban-not-banning-ips.335356/). Guess it's time to do some studying of fail2ban's docs and try to understand why this works...

Answer (score 0):

It seem's you don't have actual `action` defined. Try adding this line

```
action = %(action_)s
```